# Query a string on array element in api with url enpoint

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, dsl

I'm using the Art Institute of Chicago API (https://api.artic.edu/docs/#introduction) and there is an element called subject_titles which is an array of strings. I want to query the API to show me all the results which contain the string "landscapes" in the subject_titles, rather than scrape the API and search for the string on my end.

Some failed examples of what I have tried:

`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=[subject_titles]=landscapes`

`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[terms][subject_titles]=landscape`

I reckon it would be replacing '[terms]' with a different specifier, but I can't find which. All my research comes up with results that use the Elasticsearch API, but I'm pretty new to this and that seems like a can of worms I don't want to open (why do I need one API to query another API? Also DSL looks like a headache to learn synatx-wise), but I will learn it if I have to. Is there a way to do this using the simple REST style url endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[match][subject_titles]=landscape`

If you want an more detailed explanation, I think they tried to make the interface powerful and concise so you can do structured queries with just an url, but I agree, it is a bit confusing.

It looks like the URL parameters are getting translated into top level elements in the DSL and if values start with something like `foo[bar]` they are getting translated into foo with bar nested inside. So if you have `foo[bar][baz]=10` it will be translated into

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
     "baz": 10
    }
  }
}
```

With this information in mind we can reverse engineer `query[term][is_public_domain]=true` into

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "is_public_domain": true
    }
  }
}
```

If we now open [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) we can figure out that `term` is the type of the query and this query will search all documents were the field `is_public_domain` contains `true`. We need to search for another field and another value. So, if we replace `is_public_domain` with `subject_titles` and `true` with `landscape`. Term works well for boolean fields such as `is_public_domain` but it is better to search strings with another query type - `match`. So we should also replace `term` with `match`. At the end we will get the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "subject_titles": "landscape"
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can convert it back into URL representation: `query[match][subject_titles]=landscape` and if we stick it back on the URL we get

`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[match][subject_titles]=landscape`

This will give us the first 10 hits. If we want more, we can add limit:

`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[match][subject_titles]=landscape&limit=100`

and if we want even more we can start paging through the results using the page parameter

`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[match][subject_titles]=landscape&limit=100&page=2`

Comment: What a wonderful answer, thank you. Do you know why this endpoint would respond with objects that don't contain 'landscapes' in subject_titles, but contain 'landscapes' in other elements? For example, the first result I get with this endpoint (https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=query[query_string][subject_titles]=landscape&limit=100&fields=*) contains 'landscapes' in artist_title, but not in subject_titles. It is a landscape (https://www.artic.edu/iiif/2/1e452e34-3a2b-0dca-35c3-c7236c612985/full/1686,/0/default.jpg).

Comment: But how do you know what’s in the subjects_titles? It doesn’t seemed to be returned as one of the fields.

Comment: The same endpoint with '&fields=*' shows certain subject_titles as '[]'. I could've given a more exact link.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the URLs. The `q=` was messing things up.

Comment: Its not that either, must be in imprecision on their end.

Comment: No, it is definitely that. Try new URLs - they now find 1176 records instead of 2886 as before. That part after `q=` goes into a "simple" query that searches many fields at once. If you put it in `query` with parameters it is equivalent to the actual elasticsearch query - https://gist.github.com/imotov/e453280299022f7b895abd7d69c9d0bc After you puzzled me with your follow up question I traced that part through their source code (luckily they published it on GitHub) and realized that I had an error in my URLs. It is fixed now. Please send me the request that you think still doesn't work.

Comment: Now that I look at it a second time it works (https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?query[match][subject_titles]=landscape&limit=100&fields=*).